# How to extract data from a table dynamically?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have the following table

[image]

And I would like a formula that would produce the following result

[image]

I would like to iterate through the table going from left to right top to bottom and if there is a value in a cell, I would like to return with the matching top row criteria. How would I do this?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(C2:O<>"", "♦"&C2:O&"♠"&C1:O1, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♦")), "♠")))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That's quite a formula. Your answer would benefit a lot if you could explain each part of the formula.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal if `C2:O` isn't empty each value of that range is combined with whats in row 1 eg header and two unique symbols resulting into: `♦1♠XXS` for C2. then all is smashed in one single cell with `QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 ),,999^99)),,999^99)`. once it's all in one cell the string is split by first unique symbol `♦` columns are transposed to rows and again split by 2nd unique symbol `♠`. as a final touch, the `TRIM` is used to fix for possible spaces after each value.

Comment: Great - you should edit that into your answer. Comments are temporary.